# Set value inside label using javascript

Tags: javascript

I just stumbled upon a js project where I need to set the value inside a html label tag using javascript. I tried the follwing code but, for some reason its not working. any idea why?

```
<label id="text"></label>
<script>
    document.getElementById('text').value = 'Hello World!';
</script>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Label doesn't have a `value` property. Use `textContent` instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `document.getElementById('text').textContent` instead.

```js
document.getElementById('text').textContent = 'Hello \nlcr World!';;
```

```html
<label id="text"></label>
```

There is other options, such as `.innerHtml` or `.innerText`, to see how `.textContent` differs from the others and what the benefits in using one over the other might be, see this ► https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Hello World!';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('text').innerText = 'Hello World!';
```